# Reading XML file returns wrong characters

Tags: java, xml, readfile

I have an XML file with thousands of tags to read their text content, as in the screenshot below :

[image: XML file to read]

I am trying to read the text content of all the "word" tags using this code :

```
String filePath = "...";
File xmlFile = new File( filePath );

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document domObject = db.parse( xmlFile );
domObject.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList categoryNodes = domObject.getElementsByTagName( "category" );   // Get all the <category> nodes.

for (int s = 0; s < categoryNodes.getLength(); s++) {    //Loop on the <category> nodes.
    String categoryName = categoryNodes.item(s).getAttributes().getNamedItem( "name" ).getNodeValue(); 

    if( selectedCategoryName.equals( categoryName ) ) {  //get its words.
        NodeList wordsNodes = categoryNodes.item(s).getChildNodes();

        for( int i = 0; i < wordsNodes.getLength(); i++ ) {
            if( wordsNodes.item( i ).getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE ) continue;
            String word = wordsNodes.item( i ).getTextContent();
            categoryWordsList.add( word );  // Some words are read wrong !!
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

But for some reason many words are being read in wrong manner, examples :

```
"AMK6780KBU" is read as "9826</word"

"ASSI.ABR30326" is read as "rd>ASSI.AEP26"

"ASSI.25066" is read as "SI.4268</6"
```

It might be because the file size is big. If i just add some empty lines or remove some empty lines from the XML file, other words will be read wrong than the ones mentioned above, which is a strange thing !

You can download the XML file from [here](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=7rafYLDm).

Comment: Header says that the file is in UTF-8, is it really the case?

Comment: Yes, is there a problem about that ?

Comment: That's really strange. Just for experimental purposes, try to employ SAXParser for the same task. Will it work properly with this big file? Perhaps the problem is related to the DOM parser.

Comment: I opened the XML with Firefox and it complains about the XML declaration not being well-formed. It complains about the `1.1` version. Maybe your parser has also some issue with 1.1 XML files?

Comment: Rafael .. DOM is much easier than SAX parser. Why do you want to make my life hard ? :)

Comment: orique .. I've tried using "1.0" instead. It causes the same results.

Comment: Any chance you can put the XML on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) please? I'm blocked getting to dropbox!

Comment: andyb .. I have updated the post with the new pastebin link, here is the XML link: http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=7rafYLDm

Comment: Works with jdk 1.7 and bundled xerces on windows 7. Have you tried using the latest [Xerces-J 2.11.0](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/)?

Comment: @forty-two you are correct. It is a bug in the older, bundled version of Xerces. See my answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

See below :-)

**What I tried in the process**

Changing the XML version from `1.1 -> 1.0` fixed the problem for me. I'm using Java `1.6.0_33` (as @orique pointed out in the comments).

In my tests there are definitely issues with corruption after a certain number of nodes. I narrowed it down to somewhere around `ASSI.MTK69609`. Removing everything, including that line fixed the corruption of the previous words.

The corruption is also resolved by simply changing the declaration to:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
```

and I saw zero corruption using the entire original source XML.

Similarly if you leave the version at `1.1` but remove whitespace nodes from the source, the result is as expected, for example:

```
    <word>ASSI.MTK68490</word>
    <word>ASSI.MTK6862617</word>
<word>ASSI.MTK693115</word>
<word>ASSI.MTK69609</word>
```

results in the desired output and

```
    <word>ASSI.MTK68490</word>
    <word>ASSI.MTK6862617</word>
    <word>ASSI.MTK693115</word>
    <word>ASSI.MTK69609</word>
```

is corrupted.

Removing some end-of-line "nodes" also corrected the problem, for example

```
    <word>ASSI.MTK693115</word><word>ASSI.MTK69609</word>
```

So it was all pointing towards a bug, but where...? Eventually it clicked! **Xerces**

The version of Xerces shipped with Java 1.6 (and probably 1.7) is old, old, old and buggy (for example [`#6760982`](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6760982)). In fact, I can break my test class by simply adding:

```
Document domObject = db.parse( xmlFile );
domObject.normalizeDocument(); // <-- causes following Exception

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.XML11Char.isXML11ValidNCName(XML11Char.java:340)
```

There have been [many defects fixed for XML 1.1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=status%20in%20%28Resolved,%20Closed%29%20AND%20text%20%7E%20%22xml%201.1%22), so on a hunch I downloaded the latest version `Xerces2 Java 2.11.0`.

Simply running with the most recent version resulted in the expected uncorrupted output.

```
java -classpath .;xercesImpl.jar;xml-apis.jar Foo > foo.txt
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for the effort you put into this. I checked why we do **not** have the issue: we have a recent version of xercesImpl.jar in the endorsed libs...

Comment: andyb .. When i tried changing the version to 1.0 once again i found it is working. I apologize to "orique" for this. It seems i did something wrong when i first tested this. From your explanation i hope to use XML 1.1 though. I have tried to remove all the file spaces like you did, but still wrong characters occur in the file. I test this by simply looking for "<" in the read words by the java code, and there are many of them in the output.

Comment: andyb .. I have attached the new Xerces2 Java 2.11.0 to my application, and this caused reading the XML1.1 file right :) .. Unfortunately this adds 1.5 megabytes to my application, but i see it is the best solution available. Thanks andyb :)

Answer (score 1):

We have noticed that `getTextContent()` is buggy on some Windows implementations.

Our workaround is to do something like this

```
            // getTextContent is buggy on some Java Windows Implementations
            if ( n.getNodeType(  ) == Node.ELEMENT_NODE ) {

                results [ i ] = (String) xPathFunction.evaluate( "./text()", n, XPathConstants.STRING );
            } else {  //Node.TEXT_NODE

                results [ i ] = n.getNodeValue(  );
            }
```

`xPathFunction` is an `javax.xml.xpath.XPath`. Expensive, but works reliably.

Actually in your case I would directly use an XPath and call something like,

`NodeList l = (NodeList) xPathFunction.evaluate( "/categories/category/word/text()", domObject, XPathConstants.NODESET )`

**EDIT**

Beats me! On OSX, Java 1.6.0_43, I get the same behaviour. In case there was any doubt the DOM model is buggy in Java... The wrong values seem to reliably appear at certain intervals, which looks like some bytes buffer overrun. I never got an OOM error.

Here is what I have unsuccessfully tried:

- `word.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();` instead of `word.getTextContent();` -> no change in behaviour
- use an `InputSource` as an input into the `DocumentBuilder` instead of using a `File`
- run an `XPath` ("/categories/category[@name='Category1']/word/text()") instead of looping over the nodes and manually traversing their children
- run the same Test using Saxon as the XPath engine
- check for "strange" characters in the XML file

I believe the `DocumentBuilder` is the culprit. It is a memory hog.

Your next best chance is to go for a SAX Parser or any other streaming parser. Since your data model is small and very simple, the implementation should be easy. To further ease implementation, you may try [XMLDog](https://code.google.com/p/jlibs/wiki/XMLDog). We use a slightly modified version to parse gigabyte size XML files successfully.

If you ever find the issue, please update this post.

Comment: Thanks .. Can you give me more details about this solution ? .. I don't actually understand it !

Comment: Get an `XPath` using `xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance(); XPath xPathFunction = xPathFactory.newXPath(  );` then run the `evaluate` above; alternatively simply replace `wordsNodes.item( i ).getTextContent();`by `wordsNodes.item( i ).getNodeValue();`in your code; it may just work if you `wordNodes` are all of type `Node.TEXT_NODE`

Comment: No, getNodeValue() always returns null for me. All my nodes are of type Node.ELEMENT_NODE.

Comment: Then you need to get the Text Node within this ELEMENT_NODE and call getNodeValue or as described above use the xPath call `(String) xPathFunction.evaluate( "./text()", n, XPathConstants.STRING );`. Honestly, you should go for the XPath solution  you will replace your nested loops and ifs in a single line call followed by a simple loop making your code look much more readable.

Comment: I have used: String word = wordsNodes.item( i ).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(); .. And the results are exactly the same !

Comment: Can you check what the local name of `wordsNodes.item( i )` and list its children ? e.g. Are you sure your are on the `<word>` element ?

Comment: I am sure all is right. I have debugged it many times. I can create a small Jar sample to try it if you like.

Comment: I do not have time right now but I will run a test using your code later today and let you know

Comment: BGR ... You were of great help. At least i am sure there is a real problem here and it is not only me. I am using Java 1.6 also but on Win XP operating system. I will update the post with what i will find.